# preg_match_all to parse an xml-like attribute string

Tags: php, regex, attributes, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a string like so:

```
option_alpha="value" option_beta="some other value" option_gamma="X" ...etc.
```

I'm using this to parse them into name & value pairs:

```
preg_match_all("/([a-z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*[\"\'](.+?)[\"\']/is", $var_string, $matches)
```

Which works fine, unless it encounters an empty attribute value:

```
option_alpha="value" option_beta="" option_gamma="X"
```

What have I done wrong in my regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[\"\'](.+?)[\"\']
```

should be

```
[\"\'](.*?)[\"\']
```

**`*`** instead of `+`. The first means there can be zero to whatever occurrences of the previous expression (so it can be omitted, that is what you need). The latter means, there **has to be at least one**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the very middle of your expression from `(.+?)` to `(.*?)`.  That makes it a non-greedy match on any character (including no characters), instead of a non-greedy match on at least one character.

```
preg_match_all("/([a-z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*[\"\'](.*?)[\"\']/is",$var_string,$matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are right in that you need to change the middle of the expression, but I would change it to [^\"\']* which means "any character that is not a ", 0 or more times.  This ensures the greediness doesn't match more than it is supposed to and allows for empty "".

your expression becomes
    "/([a-z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*[\"\'][^\"\']*[\"\']/is"

note you can change the [a-z0-9_] to [\w_] which would also for upper case characters.